# Subfunctor of a hom functor in a Boolean topos

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, boolean-algebra, sheaf-theory, topos-theory

There is a wrong argument below. The conclusion is not correct but I can't figure out why. Could anyone tell me why it is not correct?

Let X be any space and suppose the category of all sheaves $Sh(X)$ is Boolean. Let $1=Hom(-,X)$, then the subobject of $1$ in $Sh(X)$ can only be itself or $0$ as every subobject of $1$ gives a sieve, either the subobject or its complement contains $id_X$ hence contains the whole $Hom$ functor. If so, by the fact that there is an isomorphism $\mathcal{O}(X) \cong Sub_{Sh(X)}(1)$, there are only two elements in $\mathcal{O}(X)$ but this conclusion is not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> either the subobject or its complement contains $id_X$

This is false.  For instance, if $X=\{0,1\}$, then the subobject $\operatorname{Hom}(-,\{0\})$ has complement $\operatorname{Hom}(-,\{1\})$, but neither contains $id_X$.  What's going on is that the join of these subobjects can contain $id_X$ even though neither one does on its own, by the gluing axiom for sheaves.

Comment: From a logical perspective, this corresponds to working with truth-values which are pairs of Booleans. In addition to $(\top,\top)$ and $(\bot,\bot)$, we also have $(\top,\bot)$ with complement $(\bot,\top)$.

Comment: Is it the case that the algebras on subobjects are different for a category of presheaves and a category of sheaves? If considering a presheaf category, then is the statement true for the subobject of a Hom functor?

Comment: Yes, there are more subobjects in presheaves than there are in sheaves (because there are some subpresheaves that are not sheaves; e.g., the pointwise union of the subobjects $\operatorname{Hom}(-,\{0\})$ and $\operatorname{Hom}(-,\{1\})$ in my example).  Your argument would be correct if you were talking about presheaves instead of sheaves.